# How to modify this SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an incomplete query that I need some assistance with. It currently runs with a subselect which is inefficient and I am pretty sure using joins would make it a later faster. 
Also, there is an element to the query that needs to be added that I'm not quite sure how to do. Details:

I have 3 tables

```
- album
 * albumId
 * albumName

- objectTag
 * objectTagObjectId (FK reference to albumId)
 * objectTabTagId (FK reference to tagId)

- tag
 * tagId
 * tagName
```

What I am trying to do is generate a list of random albums (let's say 50) based on the tags linked to another album passed to the query.

For example, I have an album called "Britney Spears Greatest Hits" and that album is tagged with "pop" and "cheese". I then pass the query the id of that Britney album and want the query to generate a list of 50 random other albums that are tagged with "pop" and "cheese".

If there are only 20 albums with those tags then the query should populate the other 30 records with any random album irrespective of tag.

So far I can get the random albums based on tags:

```
SELECT albumId, albumName, objectTagTagId
FROM album
LEFT JOIN objectTag
  ON objectTagObjectId = albumId
WHERE objectTagTagId IN
(
  SELECT objectTagTagId
  FROM album
  LEFT JOIN objectTag
    ON objectTagObjectId = albumId
  WHERE albumId = 2471
)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0,50
```

As mentioned however, this is inefficient and incomplete:

a) How do I make this more efficient with a join instead of a subselect? Is that possible?

b) How does this query need to be modified so that if there are only x amount of records that match the tags (let's say 20) that the remainder are filled with random records irrespective of tag?

Comment: Are you sure the SQL snippet is correct?  Nowhere are you `SELECT`ing from, or `JOIN`ing to, the `tag` table.  It seems that all entries in both joins will be associated with just the single album.

Comment: The join to the tag table was deliberately left out to keep the query simple. The only reason for the join to the tag table is to get the tag name so it has no effect on this problem. You are correct that the results will be associated to the single album. They are supposed to be - the association is the album's tags.

Comment: Ok.  To me, the question seems unclear, because your intended purpose is to return `albumId`s that are *different*, and I do not see how your current SQL statement will do that.  Therefore, understanding what you're asking regarding how to improve or optimize the query given is unclear, since the SQL query, as you've given it, does not seem to do what you want to begin with.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: You are correct - that is why in my issue I said that the query is incomplete. See David Chen's response below. He understood perfectly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i cannot vouch for efficiency but here's an idea...

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT albumId, albumName, objectTagTagId FROM (
    (
    SELECT count(*) AS cnt, Out.albumId, Out.albumName, objectTagTagId
    FROM album Src
    JOIN objectTag sT
      ON (Src.ablumId = sT.objectTagObjectId)
    JOIN objectTag oT
      USING (objectTabTagId)
    JOIN album Out
    ON (Out.albumId = oT.objectTagObjectId)
    WHERE Src.albumId = 2471
        AND Out.albumId != 2471
    GROUP BY albumId, albumName, objectTagTagId
    )
    UNION     
    (
    SELECT 0 AS cnt, albumId, albumName, null AS objectTagTagId
    FROM album
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 50
    )

  ) foo ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 50
) goo ORDER BY RAND()
```

the count(*) / group by will count the number of tags an album has in common with the src album.

The union will give us 50 filler albums with a cnt of zero, which is ORDERED to the bottom of foo by the ORDER BY and LIMIT.

the ORDER BY RAND() on goo will randomize the order

Comment: This is working like a charm and very fast - so thanks for this. Just one small thing though. If an album is tagged with objectTagTagId 1 and 20 for example, then I get an two of the same albums in the recordset, one for each tag. How would you modify the query so that there are no duplicate albums in the recordset? Thanks

Comment: oh sorry, please remove the objectTagTagId from the Group by clause, so that it is just GROUP BY albumId, albumName.

Comment: Hrm... wait.. you want to see the tag_id but you don't want them in seperate rows ?  you'll need to use some aggregate function

Comment: in the case of multiple tags, which tag id do you want? either? both?

Comment: I don't actually need the tag id. But don't worry, I have managed to modify the query as needed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write the intended query without nesting and by means of a simple join only, since you require ALL tags of the album 2471 to be present in the albums you would like to return. You can, of course, replace IN-nesting by EXISTS-nesting etc.